# Duplicate rows based on quantity value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft's Access as a platform to run SQL and I'm attempting to get the following output based on a query:

For example, take the following row:

```
A | B | C | 3
```

From that row, I would like to get 3 rows, as the following:

```
A | B | C | 1
A | B | C | 1
A | B | C | 1
```

"3" is the quantity in the example above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I have an existing table with many fields that only a few of which interest me.
I need to "break" the line to x lines (based on the quantity) in order to run a different query which will allow me to create a relation between a deliveries table to a sales table

Comment: I might by wrong, but I guess you don't need to have those lines split up. Maybe a normal `INNER` or `LEFT JOIN` will do the job. Better post your original tables and tell the required relation.

Comment: `SELECT 'A','B','C',quantity/3 UNION ALL SELECT 'A','B','C',quantity/3 UNION ALL SELECT 'A','B','C',quantity/3`

Comment: @Luuk the value 3 was just an example, I have different Quantities by which I'm interested in duplicating the rows

Comment: @Luuk - I don't think that this will work for the OP, as I think that what is being asked for is repeat A/B/C with a quantity of 1 for however many times indicated in the original data.

Comment: @AppsBoss7 - is a VBA solution that takes the original data and spits it out to a separate table for further processing acceptable?

Comment: @Applecore Yeah, if it does the job it will be great

Answer (score 0):

Below is a VBA solution that opens a recordset based on the original table ("tblData"), and then loops each record as many times as needed inserting the required information into a temp table ("tblTempData"):

```
Sub sSplitData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSteer As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngLoop As Long
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set rsSteer = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblData;")
    If Not (rsSteer.BOF And rsSteer.EOF) Then
        db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblTempData;"
        Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTempData WHERE 1=2;")
        Do
            For lngLoop = 1 To rsSteer!Quantity
                With rsData
                    .AddNew
                    !Field1 = rsSteer!Field1
                    !Field2 = rsSteer!Field2
                    !Field3 = rsSteer!Field3
                    !Quantity = 1
                    .Update
                End With
            Next lngLoop
            rsSteer.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsSteer.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    rsSteer.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set rsSteer = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sSplitData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
However, the VBA isn't working for me, I keep getting an error saying
"User-defined type not defined" over the DAO.DataBase line.
I changed the tblData in the " " to Deliveries (the name of the table) but it isn't working.
Do you have any idea in regards to what I should do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add a reference to DAO. From a module, select Tools|References, and then select "Microsoft DAO" from the list of available references.

Comment: Ok, I added that.
What else should I change? Because it says that it can't find sSplitData, and when I change it (in the quotes) to "Quantity", the name of the column to split, it isn't working

Comment: "Quantity" is the field in table "Deliveries" that has how many times you want the records to be repeated. `rsSteer!Field1` is the first piece of data in "Deliveries" to be repeated.

Comment: I created a new question with what I specifically need, if you can answer it instead since this probably won't entirely solve my problem I will really appreciate it.
Thanks either way for the attempt to help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546279/combine-two-tables-into-one

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate table of numbers -- which can be quite helpful under many circumstances -- you can use:

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c, 1
from t inner join
     numbers as n
     on n.n <= t.cnt;
```

Unfortunately, there is no really efficient way to create such a table in the same SQL statement.  You can create such a table using an `identity` column (I don't think MS Access has gaps in identity columns).